# C++ Vectors Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am working on a program that has an input file and it either adds, removes, or prints the string. I have my `print` function working, but I am getting a segmentation fault when I uncomment the lines of code shown.

```
int main()
{
    vector <string> vec; //Creates an empty vector
    string command;
    string word;
    int index;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("datalabvec.dat"); //Opens the input file

    if (!fin)
        cout << "The input file does not exist" << endl << endl;
    else
    {
        fin >> command;

        while (fin)
        {
            if (command =="Add")
            {
                fin >> word >> index;
                //addVec (vec, word, index);
            }
            //if (command == "Remove")
            //{
                //fin >> index;
                //remVec (vec, index);
            //}
            // else //Print function
            {
                printVec(vec);
            }
            fin >> command;
        }
    }
}

void addVec(vector <string> &v, string word, int ind)
{
    int size = v.size();
    if (ind > size + 1)
        cout << "Invalid adding at index " << ind << endl;
    else
    {
        v.insert(v.begin()+ind, word);
    }
}

void remVec(vector <string> &v, int ind)
{
    int size = v.size();
    if (ind > size)
        cout << "Invalid removing at index " << ind << endl;
    else
    {
        v.erase(v.begin() + ind);
    }
}

void printVec(const vector <string> v)
{
    int size = v.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << v[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

## Input File

```
Remove      0
Add Student 0
Add Kid     0
Add Final   1
Add Grow    1
Add Note    2
Add Bad     6
Remove      5
Add Worse   -1
Print
Add Rich    5
Remove      1
Remove      7
Add Mind    2
Remove      3
Print
```

Comment: You mentioned commented code, but there aren't any comments in your example...  Actually, your print function is missing as well.

Comment: That's because both of your functions allow UB for some inputs. Fix your comparisons.

Comment: Is there a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adding function. I guess mistakenly you wrote size+1 inside if statement. It should be size-1 because the last member of vector is at size-1. [0] - [size-1]. Correct statement is if(ind >= size) or ind > size-1. Like you used in for loop in writer function.

And as Brad suggested in comment below. It is good idea to check weather ind >= 0 or not.

```
void addVec (vector <string> &v, string word, int ind)
{
  int size = v.size();
  if (ind < 0 || ind >= size)
    cout << "Invalid adding at index " << ind << endl;
  else
    {
      v.insert(v.begin()+ind, word);
    }
}

void remVec (vector <string> &v, int ind)
{
  int size = v.size();
  if (ind < 0 || ind >= size)
    cout << "Invalid removing at index " << ind << endl;
  else
    {
      v.erase(v.begin() + ind);
    }
}
```

Comment: clearly, one must also compare the index against zero.

Comment: Cannot index be 0?